# Convert a Tensorflow dataset containing inputs and labels to two NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using Tensorflow 2.9.1. I have a `test_dataset` object of class `tf.data.Dataset`, which stores both inputs and labels. The inputs are 4-dimensional Tensors, and the labels are 3-dimensional Tensors:

```py
print(tf.data.Dataset)
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(64, 5, 548, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(64, 1, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))>
```

The first dimension is the minibatch size. I need to convert this Tensorflow Dataset to two NumPy arrays, `X_test` containing the inputs, and `y_test` containing the labels, **ordered in the same way**. In other words, `(X_test[0], y_test[0])` must correspond to the first sample from `test_dataset`. **Since the first dimension of my tensors is the minibatch size, I want to concatenate the results along that first dimension.**

How can I do that? I've seen two approaches:

#### np.concatenate

```
X_test = np.concatenate([x for x, _ in test_dataset], axis=0)
y_test = np.concatenate([y for _, y in test_dataset], axis=0)
```

But I don't like it for two reasons:

1. it seems wasteful to iterate twice on the same dataset
2. `X_test` and `y_test` are probably not ordered in the same way. If I run

   X_test  = np.concatenate([x for x, _ in test_dataset], axis=0)
   X_test2 = np.concatenate([x for x, _ in test_dataset], axis=0)

`X_test` and `X_test2` are different arrays, though of identical shape. I suspect the dataset is being shuffled after I itera through it once. *However*, this implies that also `X_test` and `y_test`, in my snippet above, won't be ordered in the same way. How can I fix that?

#### tfds.as_numpy

[tfds.as_numpy](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/as_numpy) can be used to convert a Tensorflow Dataset to an iterable of NumPy arrays:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
np_test_dataset = tfds.as_numpy(test_dataset)
print(np_test_dataset)
<generator object _eager_dataset_iterator at 0x7fee81fd8b30>
```

However, I don't know how to proceed from here: how do I convert this iterable of NumPy arrays, to two NumPy arrays of the right shapes?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the dataset twice, you can unpack the dataset and concatenate the arrays inside the resulting tuples to get the final result.

The `zip(*ds)` is used to separate the dataset into two separate sequences (`X`'s and `y`'s). `X` and `y` each becomes a tuple of arrays and you then concatenate those arrays. You can read more about how `zip(*iterables)` works [here](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/#unzipping-a-sequence).

Here is an example with `mnist` data:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', as_supervised=True)
print(ds)
# <PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>

X, y = zip(*ds)
print(type(X), type(y))
# <class 'tuple'> <class 'tuple'>
print(len(X), len(y))
# 60000 60000

X_arr = np.concatenate(X)
print(X_arr.shape)
# (1680000, 28, 1)
```

You would do the same concatenation with your `y`'s. I am not showing it here because this dataset has different dimensionality.  `np.concat` is used here since you want to join arrays on the first existing axis.

If needed, unpacking could also be done on the iterable created by the `tfds.as_numpy()` method:

```
X, y = zip(*tfds.as_numpy(ds))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I realized I forgot something important - the first dimension is the batch dimension (my minibatches are of size 64, which matches with what reported by `print(test_dataset)`. This means that I do want to stack them along the first axis, thus `np.concatenate` should be used rather than `np.stack`. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Done. Can you double check that my edit makes the question more clear? Otherwise, feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: since I need to concatenate along the first dimension, I think your answer has to be modified. Also, can you explain what this line does? `zip(*ds)`